# What is an ?????? Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **?????? Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| ?????? Words™ | Not ?????? Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| think | hear |
| heavy | overweight |
| family | neighbor |
| native | endemic |
| anxiety | stress |
| mental | theoretical |
| anime | animation |
| myth | legend |
| knife | spoon |
| white | black |
| film | movie |
| html | javascript |

These are not the only examples of ?????? Words™.

[The name I call these words is also hidden somewhere in the examples.]

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These words are

> words that, in all caps, are written with only straight lines.
>
>  (THINK, HEAVY, FAMILY vs. HEA**R**, **O**VE**R**WEI**G**HT, NEI**G**H**BOR**...)

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if this warrants its own answer, but I suspect you are calling them

> Honest Words

This is because

> The first letters of the first six words on the right spell honest, you said the name was "hidden somewhere in the examples, and the number of "?" is six, matching the length of honest.

The name and the property might not be related too directly because arguably the name is much easier to spot than the property, and should thus not give away too much of the actual puzzle.

EDIT:
The connection might be via

> Straightforward, which has a very similar meaning as honest, and also includes straight (as in straight lines).

Comment: And also, rot13(n flabalz sbe 'ubarfg' vf 'fgenvtug'). EDIT: I see you just added that.

Comment: @Lanny Strack Yes, I agree. I edited my answer around the same time as you commented. English is not my first language so this was not immediately obvious to me.